# Libgdx Moving Sprites In Unison

Tags: java, android, libgdx, tile, 2d-games

I have this class of a sprite that moves throughout a tileMap. I have stored 12 of these sprites in an ArrayList. I was wondering how could I make all of these sprites move in unison and follow the same path? This sprite is a centipede-like segment which I want to use to make the centipede. I know it has something to do with updating the segment's position from the tail of the ArrayList. Here is the class, note one cell is eight pixels.

```html
  public class CentipedeHead extends Sprite {

        enum State{
            LEFT,RIGHT,DOWN
        }

        State currentState,previousState ;

        public static final float DOWN_MOVEMENT=7f;
        public float downMovCounter;
        public float speed;
        public float stateTime;
        TextureRegion image;
        Vector2 position,size;
        Animation<TextureRegion> animation;
        TextureRegion currentFrame;
        TextureRegion[]frames;

        public CentipedeHead(TextureRegion image, Vector2 position, Vector2 size) {
            super(new TextureRegion(image));
            setPosition(position.x,position.y);
            setSize(size.x,size.y);
            currentState=State.LEFT;
            previousState=State.LEFT;
            speed=8f;
        }

        public void update(TiledMap map) {

            float delta=Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            Gdx.app.log(" "+getX()+" "+getY()+" "+delta,"Data");

            if(currentState ==State.LEFT){
                setPosition(getX()-speed*delta,getY());

                if(getX()<0) {
                    previousState=currentState;
                    currentState = State.DOWN;
                    setFlip(true,false);
                }
            }

            if(currentState ==State.RIGHT){
                setPosition(getX()+speed*delta,getY());
                if(getX()> 19) {
                    previousState=currentState;
                    currentState = State.DOWN;
                    setFlip(false,false);
                }
            }

            if(currentState ==State.DOWN){
                setPosition(getX(),getY()-1);
            }

            TiledMapTileLayer cur = (TiledMapTileLayer) map.getLayers().get(2);
            TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell = new TiledMapTileLayer.Cell();
            if(cur.getCell(Math.round(getX()),Math.round(getY())).getTile().getProperties().containsKey("mushroom"))
            {
                if(getCurrentState()==State.LEFT)
                {
                    setFlip(true,false);

                }
                else if(getCurrentState()==State.RIGHT)
                {
                    setFlip(false,false);
                }

                previousState=currentState;
                currentState = State.DOWN;
            }
        }
```

Comment: One way is to move each segment to the position of the previous one.

Comment: I thought about doing this but how would I control when a segment is in State.DOWN? When a segment hits the side or a mushroom, it will reverse its direction and go down a cell. How would I make the other segments follow when this happens.

Comment: The head is responsible for which direction to move and collision detection. All other segments just follow.

Comment: Also, I do not think there is a need for State.Down. If the head hits a wall, the head just moved down one automatically then reverses the state from left to right or vice versa.

Comment: Finally, only the head tracks the state. All other segments just move to where the preceding segment was.

Comment: I'll try this stuff and comment about my progress tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by unison exactly?

Comment: Twelve sprites that are connected and move in a train which all follow the same path.